# How to round the decimal?

Tags: stored-procedures

I have problem in rounding the number with decimal

search result I only got the following answer. 
select round(1.12,1) it takes as 1.10.
select round(1.15,1) it takes as 1.20.

But I need the result like below.

```
Ex: 12.34  = 12.30
Ex: 12.35 = 12.35
Ex: 12.36 = 12.40
Ex: 12.95 = 12.95
Ex: 12.96 =13.00
```

Pls help me

Maideen

Comment: are you sure about 12.36 = 12.40 ?? should it not round down to 12.35?

Comment: what software are you talking about, SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Also, please define exactly the business rule you need.  It sounds like you are trying to round to a nickel (assuming dollars/cents).  If the penny lands on the nickel, then stay put, else round down if less than a nickel, and round up if more than a nickel.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, and you want to round to 0 / 5 in the two points after the decimal, I would do something like:

```
out = round(in * 20.0) * 0.05
```

What that basically does is multiplying your number `in` with 100 to operate on integers rather than floats. Then you divide by `5` to round to positions of 0 or 5 only (100 / 5 = 20). After rounding you multiply `0.05` back on the result to get your old range back.

You can change `round` to `floor` or `ceil` if that was what you were after.

Comment: very nice, was about to post the same except i would have divided by 20 instead. Not that it would have been better - same logic. It will however round down in some situations where it should have rounded up. I guess your comment is asking about exactly that

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want (on SQL Server.) And I can't think of a more straightforward way off the top of my head.

```
round(x, 1, 1) +
    0.05 * case round(x * 100, 0, 1) % 10
        when 6 then 2 when 7 then 2 when 8 then 2 when 9 then 2
        when 5 then 1
        else 0
    end
```

I thought about it a bit and you may prefer this one instead:

```
    case round(x * 100, 0, 1) % 10
        when 5 then round(x, 1, 1) + 0.05 -- truncate and add back the 0.05
        else round(x, 1)                  -- round normally
    end
```